# I want to make alert while file deleted in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
router.delete('/:id',(req,res)=>{

Post.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).then(post=>{

    fs.unlink(uploadDir + post.file,(err)=>{

        post.remove();
        res.redirect('/admin/posts?resp=deleted');
    });



});
```

});

How to reflect changes to the UI after deleting the Post

Comment: which template engine you are using for the UI??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your express server is redirecting the page with the url query string set with

```
?resp=deleted
```

on the client page when the page loads you need to check if the page has loaded with this location href query . If it has then you display a message to the user.

Here is an example of code to check on your client when the page is loaded in the browser... if the query contains the response deleted has been posted on Stackoverflow before... but here it is

```
var search = location.search.substring(1);
var responseObj = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
if(responseObj.resp === 'deleted'){alert('It was deleted!')}
```

Comment: Sir,it's working fine but if i want to do this by callback then how could i do.

Comment: I think this is depending on what you mean by the word "callback".... If you are asking how you can make different alerts depending on each query response?

Comment: Yeah on every response how it will work... and also please elaborate this line also var responseObj = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')